# Android: Design option for grid of buttons?

Tags: android, layout

I need to design a grid of 2x30 buttons on the screen with labels of names.

What's the best layout-way to create the 2 groups of buttons given the button info/color/title will be populated from a database.

I was thinking a TableLayout perhaps, then in code create the buttons and add them to cells?

Comment: Yes, that.  TableLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "2x30" = 30 rows, `TableLayout` would need to be inside a `ScrollView`, as you won't have enough room on all screens to show all of that. Your alternative would be a `GridView` -- that's what the launcher uses, for example.